# Python subclass that takes superclass as argument on instantiation?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I am trying to create a wrapper class in Python with the following behaviour:

- It should take as an argument an existing class from which it should inherit all methods and attributes
- The wrapper class methods should be able to use Python super() to access methods of the superclass (the one passed as an argument)

Because of my second requirement I think the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601052/class-that-takes-another-class-as-argument-copies-behavior) will not suffice (and in any case I am having separate issues deepcopying some of the methods of the superclass' I am trying to inherit from).

I tried this but it's not correct...

```
class A:
    def shout(self):
        print("I AM A!")

class B:
    def shout(self):
        print("My name is B!")

class wrapper:
    def __init__(self, super_class):
        ## Some inheritance thing here ##
        # I initially tried this but no success...
        super(super_class).__init__() # or similar?

    def shout(self):
        print('This is a wrapper')
        super().shout()
```

And this is the behaviour I require...

```
my_wrapper = wrapper(A)
my_wrapper.shout()
# Expected output: 
# > This is a wrapper
# > I AM A

my_wrapper = wrapper(B)
my_wrapper.shout()
# Expected output: 
# > This is a wrapper
# > My name is B!
```

Is inheritance the correct approach here, if so am I sniffing in the right direction? Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Edit for context:

I intend to build multiple wrappers so that all of my ML models have the same API. Generally, models from the same package (sklearn for example) have the same API and should be able to be wrapped by the same wrapper. In doing this I wish to modify/add functionality to the existing methods in these models whilst keeping the same method name.

Comment: Does the wrapper have to be a class? Seems it's easier to just have a function that creates the class you want.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve with this ? There are different technically valid ways to get a similar result, but which is the right one depends on the concrete use case...

Comment: I intend to build multiple wrappers so that all of my ML models have the same API. Generally, models from the same package (sklearn for example) have the same API and should be able to be wrapped by the same wrapper. In doing this I wish to modify/add functionality to the existing methods in these models whilst keeping the same method name.

Comment: Calling ``super`` *for another object* means that you rely on it being a subclass. This breaks encapsulation, because you depend on the object's implementation. In your code, there are neither super nor subclasses. TLDR: Using ``super`` like this is never what you want to do.

Comment: "It should take as an argument an existing class from which it should inherit all methods and attributes" Inheritance is a relation between *classes*. Your setup requires an *instance* to "inherit" from a class. You may want to look at mixins, proxies and wrappers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went for a function in the end. My final solution:

```
class A:
    def shout(self):
        print("I AM A!")

class B:
    def shout(self):
        print("My name is B!")

def wrap_letter_class(to_wrap):

    global letterWrapper

    class letterWrapper(to_wrap):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

        def shout(self):
            print('This is a wrapper')
            super().shout()

        def __getstate__(self):
            # Add the wrapper to global scope before pickling
            global letterWrapper
            letterWrapper = self.__class__
            return self.__dict__

    return letterWrapper()
```

Which produces the desired behaviour...

```
In [2]: wrapped = wrap_letter_class(A)

In [3]: wrapped.shout()
This is a wrapper
I AM A!

In [4]: wrapped = wrap_letter_class(B)

In [5]: wrapped.shout()
This is a wrapper
My name is B!
```

Something not mentioned in my initial question was that I intended to pickle my custom class, this is not possible if the class is not defined in the global scope, hence the __getstate__ and global additions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If wrapper has to be a class then a composition solution would fit much better here.

Keep in mind that I turned the `shout` methods to `staticmethod` because in your example you pass the class to `wrapper.shout`, not an instance.

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def shout():
        print("I AM A!")


class B:
    @staticmethod
    def shout():
        print("My name is B!")


class wrapper:
    def __init__(self, super_class):
        self._super_class = super_class

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return self.__dict__[item].__func__
        except KeyError:
            return self._super_class.__dict__[item].__func__

    def a_wrapper_method(self):
        print('a wrapper attribute can still be used')


my_wrapper = wrapper(A)
my_wrapper.shout()

my_wrapper = wrapper(B)
my_wrapper.shout()

my_wrapper.a_wrapper_method()
```

Outputs

```
This is a wrapper
I AM A!
This is a wrapper
My name is B!
a wrapper attribute can still be used
```